# How can I cover the expansion gap for flooring near patio doors?

Tags: flooring

I'm putting in a bamboo floor and have a 20mm expansion gap around the entire floor. Against walls I will cover the gap with baseboards but what is the best way to hide the gap otherwise? One side of the very long room is floor to ceiling windows and patio doors so there cannot be any baseboards there. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation when I redid my basement - couldn't put baseboard in to hide the gap between the doorway and the laminate flooring at the entry door. The most common solution I've seen in images I found on the web and in my chosen home improvement store was to use color coordinated T-moulding along the doorway right up against the bottom sill. I'd add an image, but I don't have one handy, alas.

Answer (score 0):

They make a transition piece, wood to carpet piece, that you could put there. When I did my floating floor with bamboo, ~1400 sq/ft of it, I ran the wood directly up against the bottom of the door. Expansion hasn't been an issue in our hot humid environment since it can move everywhere else. You have to take this all into consideration though prior to starting as I had to trip the pieces under the base molding a bit shorter so everything lined up. Also, in my case the flooring all ran parallel to the doors.